# Get selected index in QListView using QStandardItemModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

I am creating a QListView and QStandardItemModel using this code:

```
self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.groupBox2)
self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 20, 400, 220))
self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
```

I am adding items in a loop using something similar to:

```
self.item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem("Itemname1")
self.entry.appendRow(self.item1)
self.item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem("Itemname2")
self.entry.appendRow(self.item2)
```

How can I assign those items to a list knowing 0 in the list stands for "Itemname1", 1 stands for "Itemname2" etc.?

Also, how can I set an item in the QListView as selected?
`setSelected()` doesn't seem to exist for QStandardItemModel

Answer (score 4):

`QStandardItemModel` is a model so you can use all the methods of `QAbstractItemModel` as `rowCount()` that tells us the number of rows, so you iterate over them and using the `item()` method you get the `QStandarItem` associated with each index, and then use the `text()` method of the `QStandarItem` to get the text.

```
l = [self.entry.item(i).text() for i in range(self.entry.rowCount())]
print(l)
```

On the other hand if you want to select an element of a view that inherits from `QAbstractItemView` as in this case `QListView` you must use the `QItemSelectionModel` associated with the view that will be obtained using the method `selectionModel()`. The `QItemSelectionModel` has several methods to select and deselect in different ways, in this case you must use the method select and pass the flag `QItemSelectionModel::Select`. On the other hand, by default the views are enabled to select a single element, if you want more elements to be selected you must use the `setSelectionMode()` method and pass it the flag `QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection`.

Example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("to list")
        button.clicked.connect(self.modelToList)
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.listView)

        self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.entry) 

        for text in ("Itemname1", "Itemname2", "Itemname3", "Itemname4"):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
            self.entry.appendRow(it)

        self.listView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        sm = self.listView.selectionModel()
        for item in (self.entry.item(1), self.entry.item(2)):
            index = self.entry.indexFromItem(item)
            sm.select(index, QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Select)

    def modelToList(self):
        l = [self.entry.item(i).text() for i in range(self.entry.rowCount())]
        print(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

If you only want to select an item then you must use `setCurrentIndex()` since it internally calls the `select()` method of `selectionModel()`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from random import randint


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("to list")
        button.clicked.connect(self.modelToList)
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.listView)

        self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.entry) 

        for text in ("Itemname1", "Itemname2", "Itemname3", "Itemname4"):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
            self.entry.appendRow(it)

        item = self.entry.item(randint(0, self.entry.rowCount()-1))
        self.listView.setCurrentIndex(self.entry.indexFromItem(item))

    def modelToList(self):
        l = [self.entry.item(i).text() for i in range(self.entry.rowCount())]
        print(l)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5       import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor 

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.label    = QtWidgets.QLabel("Please Select item in the QListView")
        lay.addWidget(self.listView)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)

        self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.entry)

        self.listView.clicked[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(self.on_clicked)
        # When you receive the signal, you call QtGui.QStandardItemModel.itemFromIndex() 
        # on the given model index to get a pointer to the item        

        for text in ["Itemname1", "Itemname2", "Itemname3", "Itemname4"]:
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
            self.entry.appendRow(it)
        self.itemOld = QtGui.QStandardItem("text")

    def on_clicked(self, index):
        item = self.entry.itemFromIndex(index)
        self.label.setText("on_clicked: itemIndex=`{}`, itemText=`{}`"
                           "".format(item.index().row(), item.text()))
        item.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0))) 
        self.itemOld.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0))) 
        self.itemOld = item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]