# Why QListView gives me a NoneType while trying to retrive text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, nonetype, qlistview

I'm writing a simple file searcher in PyQt5 (full code down here).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, os, platform, fnmatch
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

sep = os.sep
Ot = platform.system()
file_name = os.path.basename(__file__)
file_path = __file__.replace(file_name, '')

def find(ext, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, ext):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    _ = dirs # For PyLint
    return result

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(804, 554)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Users/Luger/Pictures/ico/search.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.folderButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.folderButton.setFont(font)
        self.folderButton.setObjectName("folderButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.folderButton)
        self.extensionLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.extensionLineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.extensionLineEdit.setMaxLength(25)
        self.extensionLineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.extensionLineEdit.setObjectName("extensionLineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.extensionLineEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.searchButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.searchButton.setObjectName("searchButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.searchButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.listView.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.entry)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 804, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.folderButton.clicked.connect(self.fileChooserFunct)
        self.searchButton.clicked.connect(self.searchButtonFunct)
        self.listView.clicked[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(self.on_clicked)

    def fileChooserFunct(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.dir_to_scan = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, 'Select A folder:', f'{file_path[0]}:{sep}', QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        self.folderButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", f" Selected: {self.dir_to_scan} "))
        self.folderButton.adjustSize()
        if Ot == 'Windows': self.dir_to_scan = self.dir_to_scan.replace('/', '\\')

    def searchButtonFunct(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.searchButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Searching, please wait..."))
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File Searcher - Searching"))
        self.searchButton.adjustSize()
        self.userExtension = self.extensionLineEdit.text()
        result = find(f'*.{self.userExtension}', self.dir_to_scan)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(model)

        for i in result:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(i)
            model.appendRow(item)

        self.searchButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search"))
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File Searcher"))
        self.searchButton.adjustSize()

    def on_clicked(self, index):
        item = self.entry.itemFromIndex(index)
        print(f"itemText='{item.text()}'")


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File Searcher"))
        self.folderButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Select a folder "))
        self.extensionLineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Extension of the file"))
        self.searchButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Based on a user answer I added this MRE (I hope it's correct)

```
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget) #create the widget
        self.listView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers) #paths cannot be modified by the user
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView") # Set his name
        self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel() #Those two I don't really know what are for
        self.listView.setModel(self.entry)

        self.listView.clicked[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(self.on_clicked) #User clicked something in QListView, calling on_clicked


    def on_clicked(self, index):
        item = self.entry.itemFromIndex(index)
        print(f"itemText='{item.text()}'") #Error is given here
```

I used QtDesigner and converted the UI file using pyuic5.exe, modified a bit and now I'm stuck at retriving the user' selected object in the QListView.

I used a bit of the code of [S.Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7767694/s-nick?tab=profile) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52043663/12726255).
Even using his code and using the same variables' names, when i click an object i get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`(His code worked without any problems).

The error is given here

```
    def on_clicked(self, index):
        item = self.entry.itemFromIndex(index)
        print(f"itemText='{item.text()}'")
```

I have started searching a solution 2 days ago and I viewed most stackoverflow's answers, sites, examples, videos (even 1 hour of two dudes speaking in russian) but still I'm blocked here.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you think it is possible to reduce the number of lines of code if you remove everything which is not absolutely neccessary? This would then make a fine [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you @Twonky ! I added the Minimal, Reproducible Example you asked you can find it at mid post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the searchButtonFunct method you are creating a new model to the QListView so that the QModelIndex belong to that new model, so using `self.entry.itemFromIndex()` with QModelIndex that does not belong to that model will return None.

The solution is to use the same model:

```
def searchButtonFunct(self):
    self.entry.clear()
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    self.searchButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Searching, please wait..."))
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File Searcher - Searching"))
    self.searchButton.adjustSize()
    self.userExtension = self.extensionLineEdit.text()
    result = find(f"*.{self.userExtension}", self.dir_to_scan)

    for i in result:
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(i)
        self.entry.appendRow(item)

    self.searchButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search"))
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File Searcher"))
    self.searchButton.adjustSize()
```